# Async confusion in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm in deep trouble trying to understand how to make my code asynchronous in Node.js land.  Please see my code below, in two varieties.

Ok so here's my first try - I have three functions here.  A processing function (iim), a file copy function (fse.copy), and an archive function (da).

I need da to happen after iim, and iim to happen after fse.copy.

This first approach results in archive happening, but it's empty because iim never appears to happen.

```
  da(randomString, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      log.error(err);
    } else {
      fse.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          log.error(err);
        } else {
          log.info("File saved to " + new_location + file_name);
          var sourceImage = new_location + file_name;
          log.debug(sourceImage);
          log.debug(randomString);

          iim(sourceImage, randomString, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              log.error(err);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

The next block is an alternate approach which results in the da happening before iim is finished.

```
  fse.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      log.error(err);
    } else {
      log.info("File saved to " + new_location + file_name);
      var sourceImage = new_location + file_name;
      log.debug(sourceImage);
      log.debug(randomString);

      iim(sourceImage, randomString, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          log.error(err);
        }
      });
      da(randomString, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          log.error(err);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: you say that you want `fse.copy` ... `iim` ... `da`. Why do you call `da` first in the first example?

Comment: What does `but it's empty` mean? And please name your functions probably.

Comment: @akonsu, too much confusion and staring at this problem for too long, I think! Sorry.  Do you have a suggestion with fse.copy ... iim ... da sequence please?

Comment: @Amberlamps, Sorry. da is an archive function, it zips a directory.  This directory is populate by image processing (iim).  In the example you speak of, the archive function happens before the image processing function can finish, resulting in an incomplete archive.  I need this all to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd recommend -- in your question you say you need to essentially run three functions in series -- correct? Run function A, then function B, and lastly, run function C.

The simplest way to do this is using the [asyncjs](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

Here's an example:

```
var async = require('async');

async.series([
  function a(cb) {
    // do stuff
    cb();
  },
  function b(cb) {
    // do stuff
    cb();
  },
  function c(cb) {
    // do stuff
    cb();
  },
], function() {
  // this will run once all three functions above have finished
});
```

Now, let's say that each of those functions needs to return data to the next function. SO imagine that function B needs input from function A to run. How do you accomplish that? Using [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall)!

```
var async = require('async');

async.waterfall([
  function a(cb) {
    // do stuff
    cb(null, 'value');
  },
  function b(val, cb) {
    // do stuff with val
    cb(null, 'woot');
  },
  function c(val, cb) {
    // do stuff with val
    cb(null);
  },
], function() {
  // this will run once all three functions above have finished
});
```

Not bad right?

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: Here's a code block showing your code above refactored using asyncjs:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(cb) {
    fse.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        log.error(err);
      } else {
        log.info("File saved to " + new_location + file_name);
        var sourceImage = new_location + file_name;
        log.debug(sourceImage);
        log.debug(randomString);
      }
      console.log('Finished running fs.copy');
      cb(null, sourceImage, randomString);
    });
  },
  function(sourceImage, randomString, cb) {
    iim(sourceImage, randomString, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        log.error(err);
      }
      console.log('Finished running iim');
      cb(null, randomString);
    });
  },
  function(randomString, cb) {
    da(randomString, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        log.error(err);
      }
      console.log('Finished running da');
      cb();
    });
  }
], function() {
  console.log('All done!');
});
```

Comment: That's actually super helpful, thank you @rdegges. :-)  I'm having difficulty equating this to my actual code since the functions aren't quite as straightforward.  Would you be willing to help me with my actual code block please?

Comment: Hey @davidjpeacock. Just added a fully refactored code sample to the bottom =)

Comment: Good grief @rdegges! Thank you so very much. This kind of thing is amazing. You're wonderful. :-)  I have further issues which must mean my modules aren't behaving.  I'll edit the put output above, basically      `console.log('Finished running iim');` and `console.log('Finished running da');` aren't being run; presumably this means those functions aren't working correctly.

Comment: Heyo! I just saw your edits (didn't approve it because it might be confusing to other SO readers), but yes. Those functions aren't working properly. What I'd do is this: open a new SO question about fixing those modules separately (include their code), then link to it from here in the comments =)

Answer (score 1):

So you can either put da into the callback for iim (right now it's not) from your second example:

```
fse.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      log.error(err);
    } else {
      log.info("File saved to " + new_location + file_name);
      var sourceImage = new_location + file_name;
      log.debug(sourceImage);
      log.debug(randomString);

      iim(sourceImage, randomString, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          log.error(err);
          return;
        }
        da(randomString, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            log.error(err);
          }
        });

      });
    }
  });
```

That said, callback depth can be flattened with the use of a library like async (https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: Callback depth can also be flattened easily and naturally, by using named functions that are written down per module "flat" instead of ever deeper inline. Combine that with a modular approach and well-defined interfaces and JS has no "callback hell".

Comment: nobody should need a whole library to write non-nested async in a closure-ready environment...

Comment: Thank you @Paul, I have actually tried your suggestion but this results in da() not being run, with no errors.  I'm further confused because this is how it 'should' work right?